# HTML Image in Table Alignment For Email

Tags: html-email

I am trying to align an image to the left, and then put text directly next to it for an email. The basic html isn't working, I am seeking help from a table guru that can show me how to simply put an image on the left and have text on the right that would work in email templates. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more for your design I don't know if there's a better way to do this than in tables.

But as you asked for tables:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="http://your.image.here"/>
</td>
<td>
Your text goes here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

That will give you a one row table, with two cells in the row. On the cell on the left will be an image, on the right will be the text.